# Make API/Ajax Call in Gatsby/React

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, gatsby

I'm fairly new to Gatsby/React but thought I'd give it a go building my personal website. I've got a restful API setup ready to call in my currently playing on Spotify, however since Gatsby is a static site builder, I'm having trouble figuring out a way to implement an API that will call dynamically without having to rebuild the site every time I listen to something different. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point, you don't need to worry. Gatsby is a static site generator, which means that it gets all the data sources (CMS, markdowns, JSONs, APIs, etc) via GraphQL queries at the time you build (and compile) your code/project. That doesn't mean that you cannot make asynchronous calls behind because it uses React, of course, you can!

### A practical example

When you compile and build your code, it generates a plain HTML, so, wherein your code you may have a `<h1>{post.title}</h1>`, once compiled it will generate `<h1>Real title</h1>` from the data gathered from the CMS. That means "static" because the code is already generated, without additional server calls. Not a "static" meaning plain, without request or whatever.

On the other hand, behind your code, you are keeping all the JavaScript logic and schema because it will generate a bundled JavaScript file with all your libraries, functions, and logic (using webpack) that will keep all your asynchronous logic if you add it.

So, of course, with React, you can make an asynchronous API request to show/hide any desired content.

In React, you have a method called `componendDidMount()` (equivalent to `useEffect` if using hooks) that triggers on every page render, once the component is loaded. From [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM
>   nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint,
>   this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

Usually, once you have a component rendered, you may want to place your API calls there. Instead of rendering a plain HTML tag, you will render the response of your API call. That's precisely the power of Gatsby and React.

[image: Gatsby flow]

I would recommend you to dive into Gatsby and explore all this potential. But summarizing, answering your question, of course, you can make an API request to show your playlist of Spotify in your site, not a big deal.